# Android doesn't say it's Ericsson, hard restart does nothing

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-x8

I bought a Sony Ericsson X8 and saw on YouTube that when we turn on this phone a page is supposed to come up and mention the name of Sony Ericsson. When I turn on my phone just it says Android and that's all.

When I wanted to hard restart it or upgrade it, I pressed the back button but nothing happens. When I hold left and right keys together, the same situation when I release.

Is my phone a fake? Why it is like that?

Answer (score 1):

Hang on a second, you wanted to hard reset your phone because your splash screen didn't look like the one on YouTube?

1. It is very common for carriers to change things like splash screens.
2. You don't say where you bought your phone or who your carrier is. Can't tell you if it is a fake.
3. If it is legit, you don't say if you bought your phone new or used or if you or a previous owner has rooted it and flashed a custom ROM. That would almost certainly change your boot splash screen.
4. I've never owned an Android phone that required pushing the back button during a hard reset. Here is the only method of hard resetting that I have ever needed:

From the main home screen, tap menu
Tap Settings, then Privacy
Tap Factory data reset
Tap Reset phone
Enter your password if required, then tap Erase everything to confirm

Comment: Would you please tell me where is backbutton exactly?
I guess the previous owner root it.
is there any way I back it to its previous version?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the 3 Android phones I've had, one had an "Android" startup splash screen, one had a manufacturer startup splash screen, and one originally had a phone network (Vodafone) startup splash screen, but was changed to a manufacturer splash screen in one of the (official) firmware updates.All were bought new and legitimate with manufacturer/carrier supplied firmware.

I don't think you can judge anything by what the splash screen shows, especially as this can be changed by carriers and changed in official firmware updates. You need to compare it to an identical hardware model, supplied through the same channel that is running the same firmware/OS version. It is unlikely that a random Youtube video happens to be identical to yours in all those ways.